# Wildcard for directory name in Jenkinsfile using publishHTML not recognized

Tags: windows, unix, jenkins-pipeline, pitest

In my Jenkinsfile I use publishHTML to publish report for [PIT](http://pitest.org/). My step is as follows

```
stage('Results') {
  publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
     keepAll: false, reportDir: 'target/pit-reports/*/', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'PIT Report'])
}
```

The directory of the index.html is something like this `\target\pit-reports\201612081633`. That last part `201612081633` is of course different every time. Using `target/pit-reports/*/` on a windows machine results in the following error.

```
ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'D:\David\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\jenkinsSandbox\target\pit-reports\*' does not exist.
```

The wildcard `*` or `**` does not work. How can I use a wildcard for a directory name in the jenkinsfile and is there any difference when doing this on windows or unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using a workaround because the publishHTML plugin seems to be unable to handle `*` or `**`. I now run pitest with `-DtimestampedReports=false org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`, which disables the timestamped folders. The result step now looks like this.

```
stage('Results') {
publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
             alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
             keepAll: true,
             reportDir: 'target/pit-reports',
             reportFiles: 'index.html',
             reportName: 'PIT Report'
             ])

}
```

For those who are interested, the full version of my Jenkinsfile can be found on my [github repo](https://github.com/daafith/jenkinsSandbox/blob/master/Jenkinsfile).